# 2008 Jeep Wrangler - Painful noise when coming to a stop

Tags: noise, jeep, brake-rotor, braking, wrangler

I have a problem that has stumped several mechanics and friends of mine who are mechanically inclined. Below is a video(sorry for poor quality) demonstrating the issue in question

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmgq3NEibkw

This disgusting squawking noise comes from the front driver's side only when I am braking. The pads, rotors, and calipers all look fine. I checked out the dust shield, and it wasn't making contact with the rotor(one theory). I checked for any lodged rocks/debris and there are none. I finally decided that maybe replacing the front driver's side rotor would at least make a difference, but no. It is still making the noise. I don't want to keep throwing parts at it until it fixes the problem without knowing what the problem is, as that is pretty costly and I want to know the source of this problem in case it happens again in the future. Thank you all for any advice you can give!

Comment: Is intensity of the sound proportional to the force applied on the brake pedal?

Comment: Are the pads wearing unevenly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Fellow Jeeper here..and I swear I’ve encountered every strange braking sound on my 2009 JKU.

Have you checked the slide/guide pins on the caliper? One could be failing and causing the pad to apply to the rotor unevenly and causing that sound.